# lynda Rails Tut: NoMethodError: undefined method `page' for #<Subject:0x

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn Rails using the lynda.com tutorial found here:

https://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Ruby-Rails-5-Essential-Training/500551-2.html

It has been pretty easy to follow so far, but I ran into a snag. When learning about Associations I'm supposed to see this (capture from course video):

[image: Instructor Success]

Instead, I get the following error:

[image: Student Failure]

> NoMethodError: undefined method `page' for #<Subject:0x

I am using the same page.rb and subject.rb that the instructor uses:

```
# page.rb file
class Page < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :subject, { :optional => false }
  has_many :sections
  has_and_belongs_to_many :admin_users

end


# subject.rb file
class Subject < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :pages

  scope :visible, lambda { where(:visible => true) }
  scope :invisible, lambda { where(:visible => false) }
  scope :sorted, lambda { order("position ASC") }
  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }
  scope :search, lambda {|query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"]) }

end
```

And the mysql database looks like this:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------------------------+
| Tables_in_simple_cms_development |
+----------------------------------+
| admin_users_pages                |
| ar_internal_metadata             |
| pages                            |
| schema_migrations                |
| section_edits                    |
| sections                         |
| subjects                         |
| users                            |
+----------------------------------+
mysql> DESCRIBE pages;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subject_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| permalink  | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| position   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| visible    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> DESCRIBE subjects;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| visible    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I've looked through quite a few stackoverflow questions related to NoMethodError, but most of them talk about 'require' and we haven't covered that yet. I am running the same rails development environment as the instructor (Rails 5.0.0). He is running on Mac and I have a Windows 10 machine, if that makes a difference.

I'm not asking anyone to "fix this for me", but I just don't know where to look next.

Comment: Turns out the first time I got this error, my db was missing a properly configured pages table. Then after all the messing around I did to try to fix it, I imported the final configuration of the page.rb and subject.rb files which had been updated to take out the one-to-one relationship. Thanks @rajbir for helping with what to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using has_many association between subject and pages which means that you can not use

```
subject.page
```

instead you should be using

```
subject.pages
```

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you. I am wondering how the instructor got away with it. It also now returns an empty array, instead of the instructor's 'nil'.

Comment: Probably you should have `has_one :page` instead of `has_many :pages` then if there is no page you will get a nil.